# Is this knockdown three-post joint resistant to racking?

Tags: joinery, mortise-and-tenon, knockdown

I am building a very large desk which has kind of a post-and-beam base construction. Since the desk is L-shaped, and roughly 5'x7', there are a couple of places where three beams come together at a corner; the vertical post, and the two cross beams.

I've been brainstorming ways that I can make a fairly stable and rack-resistant base that I can also disassemble and move, since it is too large to move fully assembled.

This is the design I came up with: A stub tenon with a threaded insert, and offset holes (in the vertical-axis) so that they are non-overlapping. I've mocked it here w/ 5/16" bolts.

When the desk top is attached, the frame is rigid in the horizontal plane (because it is constrained by the top itself). I am more concerned with racking side to side in the vertical planes, and I am not sure the single bolt/stub tenon is enough.

[image: Three-Post Joint mock up]

For reference, the vertical post is 3" square, the cross beams are 2"x3" (mostly for looks). Tenons are drawn as 0.5" long. Through Holes are counterbored for a 5/16" furniture bolt. Tennons are drilled for a threaded insert.

Comment: The bolts along with the help from the stub tenons will go a long way towards making this joint pretty stiff and stable (without the stub tenon I'd suggest coupling the bolts with projecting pegs). A tendency to rack is mainly about the input forces on whatever it is, and desks aren't especially bad in this regard because of the low static load, and generally not a huge amount of dynamic loading. The rest of the design will have as much or more to say about the stability overall. And do remember that if this is to be placed along a wall or into a corner the walls can contribute massively.

Comment: Assuming the desk is to be free-standing..... *"I am not sure the single bolt/stub tenon is enough"* There's probably no way to be sure other than to built it and see. However ahead of that there's no harm in going beefier on the bolts — up to the max reasonable diameter (I'm presuming there's a minimal cost differential going up to 1/2", 5/8" or even 3/4" bolts and associated hardware)

Comment: There's no absolute need to have the bolt threaded in here if you adopt the common-ish workbench detail of burying a nut in the stringer. But if you do want to thread it's worth repeating something that has come up a couple of times in recent months — in hardwood especially threaded inserts often aren't needed, unless the demands of assembly and knock-down are VERY high, because you can thread wood directly. This can be done by forcing in the threading, or cut using a rudimentary tap (as illustrated in a previous Answer). In either case the thread can be strengthened with superglue if desired.

Answer (score 3):

Individually, they are not particularly resistant to racking.   The stub tenons do nothing to control racking in the plane of the respective stringers, and the bolts won't hold against the leverage of the legs.   Assembled as a unit, however, if the mortices and tenons fit snugly, these will be quite solid, because each direction gets substantial racking resistance from the tenon on the stringer orthogonal to it.   For this reason, I would make the mortices deeper than 1/2".   If you make the mortices and tenons 3/4", you can easily make the them 1 or 1 1/8" deep, which will greatly improve their orthogonal holding power.   With a 1/4" 20 threaded insert, a 3/4" tenon should have adequate holding power.   I would screw the inserts in before cutting the tenon cheeks, however, or failing that, clamp the tenon sides tightly when screwing in the insert, so as to support the tenon sides.   You might also consider burying the insert in the stringer itself, with a clearance hole in the tenon.  (All these suggestions to prevent the insert from blowing out your tenon, which it's going want to do during in installation).

Comment: Thank you! "You might also consider burying the insert in the stringer itself, with a clearance hole in the tenon" -- I actually considered doing exactly this! More meat around the insert, less stress on the tenon so it doesn't explode while I thread the insert in.

Answer (score 3):

> I've been brainstorming ways that I can make a fairly stable and rack-resistant base that I can also disassemble and move, since it is too large to move fully assembled.

Taller rails would help a lot. If you make them 6" or 9" tall instead of 3", and use two bolts each instead of one, they'll be much stronger. You don't need that full height along their entire span, just where they connect to the leg.

Connecting the legs with stretchers will also help.

> A stub tenon with a threaded insert

Threaded inserts are great, but nuts with washers will spread the load over a larger area. Drill the holes into the rails as you had planned, but go deeper -- maybe 4" or so. Rout a recess into he inside face of the rails that will intersect the hole, and secure the bolt coming from the leg with a nut and a thick flat washer. You'll want a washer under the head of the bolt for the same reason.

Comment: A “cross dowel nut” might be slightly more elegant, though the nut/washer will totally work. (And better than a threaded insert nut, imho.)